# Exit code 139 while using ReadAsArray in OS X

Tags: python, gdal, mac

I'm trying to load TIFF image of DEM as a numpy array using method ReadAsArray() on Mac OS:

```
dataset = gdal.Open('DEM.tif')
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
array = band.ReadAsArray()
```

This code crashes Python with statement

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

According to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704040/exit-code-139-when-perfroming-image-subtraction, I get error 'Invalid memory access'. But in this manual I found SIGSEGV as signal for error 'Invalid memory reference'. What does it mean and how to fix it? For Windows this code works fine.

Method ReadRaster() also works fine, but I need to get a bumpy array of my data.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities here, most being related to how GDAL and its Python bindings were built but here are some things to check:

1. That the Numpy version that's actually being used is the same one as GDAL is built and linked against
2. That you can run it in lldb and get a stack trace

   `lldb -- python myfile.py`
3. That GDAL got linked against a system libtiff or something. If you didn't build GDAL yourself, you wouldn't really know this though.